# Call .NET dll from C++ code failes when calling GetProcAddress(...)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, clr

I want to call a method of .NET dll (v4.5) from C++ code. This dll uses a third party dll (SKCLNET .NET v1.0)

I build a simple C++ code for that (see below).
The problem is that GetProcAddress(...) returns NULL for some reason.
I'm not sure what is wrong with the code...

I tried to invoke the dll-function via .NET-Console-App directly this worked fine.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;

typedef std::string(*GetLicenseStatusFunction)();

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"LicenseCheck.dll");

    if (hDLL == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error loading the DLL" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    GetLicenseStatusFunction pGetLicenseStatus = (GetLicenseStatusFunction)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "ValidateLicense.GetLicenseStatus");

    if (pGetLicenseStatus == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error getting the function pointer" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string result = pGetLicenseStatus();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the structure of the used dll:

[image]

Here the ValidateLicense class in the .NET dll with the function `GetLicenseStatus()` I would like to access.
[image]

Comment: How do you exported GetLicenseStatus() in the Net dll to be visible to an unmanaged user?

Comment: @Ralf It's c+-cli, a managed version of c++.

Comment: Why do you need `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` at all ? You can consume a .NET assembly from c++-cli similar to the way you do it in C#. Note that `GetLicenseStatus` returns a managed string i.e. `String^`, not `std::string`.

Comment: Run `dumpbin /exports` on the DLL. You'll see that there is nothing for `GetProcAddress` to find.  .NET metadata is completely distinct from native DLL exports (It is possible for the same DLL to have both, but that requires advanced usage of .NET tools like `ilasm`.  The C# compiler isn't doing it for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `using namespace System;` and the prototype of `main`,
I assume this is a **C++/CLI** project (and not a native C++ one).

Since using **C++/CLI** means it is a .NET project, you can consume other .NET assemblies similarly to the way you would do that in C#.
Just use "add reference" from the project tree and add the assembly you want to consume.

`LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` are used only to load and call native functions, from native code. As explained above this is not the case here.

Note that in C++/CLI reference types use the [handle to object operator (^)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170). So from C++/CLI side the method `ValidateLicense.GetLicenseStatus` returns a `String^`.
Also in C++/CLI use `::` instead of `.` for scopes of namespaces and classes:

```
using namespace ....
//...
String^ sts = ValidateLicense::GetLicenseStatus();
```

In order to print it you can use:

```
Console::WriteLine(sts);
```

You can also convert it to a native `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
//...
std::string sts_cpp = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(sts);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tried your proposed solution and it worked to access the LicenseCheck.dll. I just had to define the namespace as 'using namespace LicenseCheck;'

Could anyone tell,whether there are things to configure in the C++/CLI project in order to find the SKCLNET.dll. Both dll's were added as References from the same location.

Comment: I am not familiar with SKCLNET.dll. Could it be a native one ? The asnwer above is relevant only for consuming a .NET DLL, from another .NET DLL.

Comment: No, it's a .NET DLL v1.0 (see screenshot in question, last line). Also it's compiled for x86 architecture. But when trying to invoke the ValidateLicense.LicenseCheck() method from .NET project it works fine... but that's not what I want.

Maybe these information related to SKCLNET.dll are helpful to elaborate better: 
`// SKCLNET, Version=4.6.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXX
// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: x86
// This assembly contains unmanaged code.
// Runtime: v1.0.3705
// This assembly is signed with a strong name key.
// Hash algorithm: SHA1`

Comment: The screenshot does not show the content of SKCLNET assembly. Do you see namespace(s), class(s) etc. (like in the LicenseCheck) ? It could be a mismatch in the architecture. Anyway - this is actually a different question from the issue with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress. I think you should consider to post a new quesrion, with all the relevant details for this issue.